# How to switch between props.value and value [from useState()] inside the component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I want the component to be able to choose whether to use the props value from parent state or the local state inside the component. Reason: sometimes I have to create 2 instances of the component (i.e. mobile and desktop view) and the state would not be sync. To fix this, I have to lift up the state which means that the component will be relying on props instead of state. This also means that for places that only has 1 instances, I would also need to lift up the state.

One solution that I could think of is to have both props and useState in the component and use conditionals to pick the right one; as shown in the code below:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface ComponentProps {
  state?: [number, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>];
}

const Component = (props: ComponentProps) => {
  const { state: state1 } = props;

  const state2 = useState(0);

  const [state, setState] = state1 ?? state2

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{state}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => prev + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const state = useState(0);

  return <Component state={state} />;
};
```

Is the following code good? If not, is there any other ways to achieve this?

Other ways I could think of:

- extract common code and create 2 components; one with props and another with state. (trying to have only 1 component)
- use contexts / global state (don't want to overcomplicate the component)
- use useEffect to sync between the states (may cause infinite loop)

Comment: You don't need second react state (the one named state), It can be just regular variable. Just const state = state1 || state2